# Windows Azure Service Bus and GCM Push Notifications

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, azure-mobile-services

This question is long and involved but I hope someone out there can give me a hand. I am writing a Phonegap app that needs to send and receive push notifications. I want to use an Azure service bus for this so I can deploy to multiple mobile platforms. Right now I am just testing Android. I have my Google and Azure accounts set up and have the code below working. When I deploy my app on my device onGcmNotification is fired and I get a regid from google. I then register with that provided regid and template after which I get an alert("Registered With Hub!") so I think everything is working. However I cannot get any push notifications to work when testing via the Azure debug console. See image below. It just keeps telling me "**No registrations were found for the selected platform**". Nothing pops up on my deployed application and onGcmNotification is never fired. What am I missing? Is there another way to accomplish what I am attempting to to?

[image: Azure Push Notification Testing Screen]

```
var GCM_SENDER_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var MOBILE_SERVICE_URL = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var MOBILE_SERVICE_APP_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var mobileServiceClient;
    var pushNotification;

    var app = {
        initialize: function () {
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        bindEvents: function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, true);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function () {
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {

                mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(MOBILE_SERVICE_URL, MOBILE_SERVICE_APP_KEY);

                // Create a pushNotification (from the PushPlugin).
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

                // Platform-specific registrations.
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                    // Register with GCM for Android apps.
                    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler,
                        {
                            "senderID": GCM_SENDER_ID,
                            "ecb": "onGcmNotification"
                        });
                } else if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
                    // Register with APNS for iOS apps.
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler,
                        {
                            "badge": "false",
                            "sound": "false",
                            "alert": "true",
                            "ecb": "onApnsNotification"
                        });
                }

                angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            });
        },
    };


    // Handle a GCM notification.
    function onGcmNotification(e) {
        switch (e.event) {
            case 'registered':
                // Handle the registration.
                if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                    console.log("gcm id " + e.regid);

                    if (mobileServiceClient) {

                        // Create the integrated Notification Hub client.
                        var hub = new NotificationHub(mobileServiceClient);

                        // Template registration.
                        var template = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"$(message)\"}}";

                        // Register for notifications.
                        // (gcmRegId, ["tag1","tag2"], templateName, templateBody)
                        hub.gcm.register(e.regid, null, "myTemplate", template).done(function () {
                            alert("Registered with hub!");
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            alert("Failed registering with hub: " + error);
                        });
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                console.log("received message: " + e.message);
                if (e.foreground) {
                    alert(e.payload.message);
                }
                break;

            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error: ' + e.message);
                break;

            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This blog post might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/17/push-notifications-to-phonegap-apps-using-notification-hubs-integration.aspx

Comment: I am experiencing the same result. Did you get any results?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same result on Azure. Push notifications are working for me though with Android. I got notifications to work for the first time by having my Mobile Service send notifications on successful insert.

In the Azure Portal, in the Mobile Service you're using go to Data->Table->Script->Insert and then use this script to send a push notification anytime there is a successful insert.

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
// Define a payload for the Google Cloud Messaging toast notification.
var payload = {
    data: {
        message: '{ "message" : "New item added: ' + item.text + '" }'; 
    }
};      
request.execute({
    success: function() {
        // If the insert succeeds, send a notification.
        push.gcm.send(null, payload, {
            success: function(pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse, payload);
                request.respond();
                },              
            error: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
                request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
                }
            });
        },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log("request.execute error", err)
        request.respond();
    }
  });
}
```

Now all registered devices should receive a notification when something is inserted into the table, even if the devices don't show up in the notification hub on Azure.

You can also send notifications from your local machine using a Node library:

https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm

I used [DevGirl's tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/) to get this working. Let me know if either of those things work. Hope that Helps!

PS. I have push notifications working for iOS and Android using code just like yours and I STILL cannot send a test notification from the debug tab of Azure's Notification Hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mobileServiceClient you shouldn't need to use the NotificationHub.

Call this instead.

mobileServiceClient.push.gcm.registerTemplate(e.regid,"myTemplate", template, null)

Also see this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I waste 2 days of my life trying to send message via Azure to my mobile apps using Notification Hub and finally i did. 
Note in function **onGcmNotification**, when you receive the registration you register a custom template. So, if you want to send message using Azure, on debug tab, select message type *Custom Template*.